# AF/O2 and Fuel Trim data - Normal or not?

Tags: toyota, o2-sensor, mileage, fuel-trims

I'm learning to diagnose my car's poor gas mileage:

Car: 2010 Toyota Matrix (Base). 
Engine: 1.8L, 4 cylinders, Auto, FWD.
ODO: 103,000km (64,000 miles).
**City gas mileage: 12.6L/100km = 18.6 mpg** 
(advertised City gas mileage is 8.1L/100km = 29 mpg)

Photo attached is data for AF, O2 sensors and Fuel Trims at idle (please click on the photo to expand the full data).

Please advise me: 
(1) if everything is normal or not? 
(2) if any other data should be read?

Thanks.

[image: (sorry if the font size on the vertical axes is too small)]

Comment: I'm curious about your rear o2 volts.  I would want to see the same data during a steady cruise.